# ISL 2006 G3:Prove that the line $AP$ bisects the side $CD$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCDE$ be a convex pentagon such that
$$ \angle BAC = \angle CAD = \angle DAE \qquad \text{and}\qquad \angle ABC = \angle ACD = \angle ADE.$$ The diagonals $BD$ and $CE$ meet at $P$. Prove that the line $AP$ bisects the side $CD$.

My Proof: Note that by $AAA$, we get $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta ADE$ . Hence $A$ is the spiral center of the spiral similarity that sends $CB$ to $ED$ . Hence, $EDPA$ is cyclic and $PACB$ is cyclic .

Now, note that, since $\angle AED= \angle ADC$ and $\angle ABC=\angle ACD$ , we have $DC$ as the common tangent of $(EDPA)$ and $(APCB)$ .

Let $AP\cap DC= M$. Note that, since $AP$ is the radical axis of $(EDPA)$ and $(APCB)$, and $DC$ is the common tangent of $(EDPA)$ and $(APCB)$ . We have $AP$ bisecting $DC$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  An alternative proof is as follows:

By the angle conditions, we require $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle ADE \sim \triangle ACD$, so $ABCD$ is similar to $ACDE$. Ceva's Theorem now implies

$$\frac{AF}{FC}\frac{CX}{XD}\frac{DG}{FA}  = 1,$$

which gives $\frac{CX}{XD} = 1$ and implies the desired result.

Comment: I see, thanks !

Comment: Nice.........+1

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct! Just justify why AP bisects DC in the proof, although it's quite well known.

Also we can show that $AEDP$ is cyclic by noticing that $\angle ADB = \angle AEC$ and similarly for $ABPC$ .

Comment: I see, thanks !

Comment: Also nice.......+1